# How would I apply the decorator pattern in a guice application?

Tags: java, decorator, guice

I would like to apply the decorator pattern in guice, not just plain old AOP that intercepts all methods, but just ones for a specific interface.  I see there were 2 community projects:

https://github.com/beluchin/decorice

But, I want the decorator to know nothing of the default implementation.  If I already setup the default module with the bindings I want, then, I'll have the problem later when I try to override that binding.  If I don't set up those bindings up front, but in the decorator module, then I must declare the default implementation I'm decorating there.

I don't like that approach, is there a better way to do it?